# How do I extract narrowed type and use it in Shapeless's coproduct?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Having this code:

```
object Types {
  val undefined = "undefined".narrow
  type RunnableArgument = BigDecimal :+: String :+: Boolean :+: CNil
}
```

I would like to have the type of the `undefined` constant as one of the `RunnableArgument` hlist elements. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton types used as HList values in scala 2.13, check the original SIP:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html

So, in your case, you can write:

```scala
RunnableArgument = "undefined" :+: String :+: Boolean :+: CNil
```

Also you can use this thing as type:

```scala
type Param = "singleton type"
```

This compiles in scastie:

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ObzN7xkKQ9egGBIv2gDuiA